# Django: Group Counts on Foreign Keys

Tags: python, sql, django

I am new to Django, transitioning from PHP. I have the below query to list the top ten counts of a grouping variable which is a foreign key to another table.

```
Model.objects.values('group').annotate(count = Count('group')).order_by('-count')[:10]
```

The data is destined for a template, detailing the 'league'. When printing to the template, I would like to list the readable name of the group as opposed to the integer foreign key value. Using values() in a query returns a dictionary rather than an object an previous methods I have used for handling foreign keys have failed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the values() queryset function, you can pull the fields of a foreign key model by using:

`.values('foreign__field')`

Referring to your example, and assuming your Group model has a "name" field, you can use:

`Model.objects.values('group', 'group__name')...`

If you pass that dict into the template, then you can refer to the `'group__name'` key:

`{% for g in groups %}
    {{ g.group__name }}`

Comment: Thanks, from my limited knowledge of Django, I suspected it would be a simple solution! That's helped me on my way.

Comment: While you're there, is there a similar method for accessing 'choices' values for a field?